# Angular 4, dotnetcore, webpack can't resolve custom font in custom theme

Tags: css, angular, webpack, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-theme

I am tying to integrate a custom theme into an angular4/aspdotnetcore application.
The template for the spa I use can be found here (https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa)

I included my custom theme files in the wwwroot/assets folder and added an import statement to include the css files into the application. The theme uses a custom font that is also located in  a subfolder of the assets folder. But, since webpack moves all css files into the dist folder, the font can't be resolved when running the application.

I tried adding an import statement for the font but this doesn't solve my problem. As the theme searches the font at a relative path '../fonts/theme-custom-font.ttf'

When running the application I get an exception that says the font can't be resolved.
I'm sure I need to add something in the webpack config to help it resolve the font but I can't figure it out.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Seems like my question is more difficult than I anticipated. Maybe it's just a limitation of webpack. Webpack not being able to handle fonts.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem as well.